# How to read only part of a text file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

So I have a text file with grades for assignments.

```
LABS
100
90
90
90
90
85
80
HOMEWORK
100
100
0
100
100
50
```

I've written code that successfully reads the file, but now I'm trying to be able to find the averages of both the Lab and the Homework grades. How do I make it so only certain lines are read so I can take only the lab grades or only the homework grades to be averaged? Do I need an array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class FinalGradeCalculator {

//Read from file

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "grades.txt";
    Scanner fileScanner = null;//Initialize fileScanner
    System.out.println("The file " + fileName + " contains the following lines:\n");
    try
    {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String fileLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(fileLine);
    }
    fileScanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Read lines and check if the content of any line match your expected content, if yes then write the lines in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and add to it all lines after "LABS" and before "HOMEWORK", then use [`IntStream#sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) to combine the numbers and divide by [`List#size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--) to get the average:

```
ArrayList<Integer> labs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String fileLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
    if (fileLine.equalsIgnoreCase("labs"))
        continue;
    if (fileLine.equalsIgnoreCase("homework"))
        break;
    labs.add(Integer.parseInt(fileLine));
}
fileScanner.close();
System.out.println("Labs average: " + labs.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()/labs.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer avoiding hardcoding. As your case is looking for a number and wants to avoid words in general you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String fileLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
    if (isInteger(fileLine)){
            marks.add(Integer.parseInt(fileLine));
        }   
    }
}
fileScanner.close();
System.out.println("Labs average: " + marks.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()/marks.size());
```

Where isInteger() is as follows:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
   boolean isValidInteger = false;
   try
      {
         Integer.parseInt(s);

         // s is a valid integer
         isValidInteger = true;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException ex)
      {
         // s is not an integer
      }
      return isValidInteger;
   }
}
```

You can do something similar for Float etc.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that is averages the labs grade *and* and the homework grade. OP only wants lab grade.